# How to merge two 2-dimensional dataframes into a multi-indexed multidimensional pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two same-sized data-frames, as follows:

```
cost_type1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4], [100,200,300,400]]).transpose()
cost_type2 = pd.DataFrame([[1,4,9,25], [10,40,90,250]]).transpose()
```

As these data-frames both relate to costs, I would want to merge them in one structure, so that I can say something like cost[i] and get the cost matrix for type i.

I tried to use multi-index as follows:

```
timestamps =["2014-01-01", "2014-02-01"]
categories = ["A", "B","C","D"]
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([timestamps,categories], names=["ts", 
"cat"])
df = pd.DataFrame(index=idx, columns=["col1", "col2"])
```

I get a nice empty data-frame like this: (out)

```
               col1 col2
ts         cat          
2014-01-01 A    NaN  NaN
           B    NaN  NaN
           C    NaN  NaN
           D    NaN  NaN
2014-02-01 A    NaN  NaN
           B    NaN  NaN
           C    NaN  NaN
           D    NaN  NaN
```

However, I can't manage to fill the "large" data frame with the two "smaller" ones that I already have. I tried something like this, but I wasn't successful:

```
df.loc["2014-01-01",:] = newdf1
df.loc["2014-02-01",:] = newdf2
```

Any of you knows how to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: Try `df.loc["2014-01-01",:] = cost_type1.values`... and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html)  with creating new index for each DataFrame, so empty DataFrame is not necessary:

```
timestamps = ["2014-01-01", "2014-02-01"]
categories = ["A", "B","C","D"]
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([timestamps,categories], names=["ts", "cat"])

df = pd.concat([cost_type1.set_index([categories]), 
                cost_type2.set_index([categories])], keys=timestamps)
df.columns=["col1", "col2"]
df.index.names=['ts','cat']
```

If input are `list of DataFrames` use list comprehension:

```
dfs = [cost_type1, cost_type2]
df = pd.concat([x.set_index([categories]) for x in dfs], keys=timestamps)
df.columns=["col1", "col2"]
df.index.names=['ts','cat']
print (df)
                col1  col2
ts         cat            
2014-01-01 A       1   100
           B       2   200
           C       3   300
           D       4   400
2014-02-01 A       1    10
           B       4    40
           C       9    90
           D      25   250
```